# VSCode Code Spell Checker extension - include .todo files

Tags: visual-studio-code, spell-checking

I'm using vscode extension for spell checking:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker

The problem is - I can't include ".todo" files type. (my .todo files are not in any markup language. They are just "plain text").

I tried(none works for me):

- "cSpell.files": ["**/**.todo"] (also turns off all existing files check)
- "cSpell.enableFiletypes": [ "*" ] to inclue all fiels types

I notice there is a languages list, but didn't find way to add new one.

Comment: It works for me out-of-the-box with no config at all.  Your `.todo` files do say `Plain Text` in the lower right, I assume?

Comment: @Mark What do you mean by  saying "do say Plain Text in the lower right"? Sorry, I don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that **by default spell check extension ignore all files from .gitignore**.

In my case solution was to add following Modifications in my vscode user settings:

```
"cSpell.enableFiletypes": [
  "todo" // enable .todo files checking
],
"cSpell.useGitignore": false, // disable ignoring files from .gitignore
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following [cSpell override](https://cspell.org/configuration/overrides/) to your `.vscode/cSpell.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "lorem ipsum",
  "enabledLanguageIds": ["plaintext"], // etc.
  "overrides": [
    {
      "filename": "**/*.todo",
      "languageId": "plaintext"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but not works for me. Also I tried to use "filename" + "language": "en" and attach it for one more file(jsut in case) - ".gitignore", this did't work either. 
For key "languageId" have tried "javaScript", "markdown", "plaintext".

All this was tried to apply from setting.json(vscode user settings file) and .vscode/cSpell.json or just cSpell.json in root.

Comment: Yes, I did try it